# How can I handle cancel event of confirm box?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I handle cancel event of confirm box?
My goal is to show the user a confirm box on clicking of browser back button and if the user press the ok button then I have to redirect it backward (/users) which is working fine but if the user presses cancel then I do not have to go to the previous page but in both the cases, it is going to the previous page.
this.router.navigate(['user-details]) is not working at all while   `window.history.pushState({}, "user-details", "/user-details");` is just changing the url, and not  the page.

```
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  r: boolean;
  confirmtxt;
  canceltxt;
  paymentList = [];
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private location: Location
  ) {
    this.getPaymentSummaryData();
  }    

  ngOnInit() {
    this.location.subscribe(x => {
      console.log(this.location);
      console.log(x);
      if (x.type === "popstate") {
        console.log("data is " + this.paymentList.length);
        const str = String(this.paymentList.length);
        console.log(str);
        this.r = confirm(
          "Are you sure?" +
            " " +
            str +
            " " +
            "applications are in the queue, awaiting decision."
        );
        console.log(this.r);
        if (this.r === true) {
          //  txt = "You pressed OK!";
          this.confirmtxt = "ok";
        } else {
         this.r = false;
  // history.forward();
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(this.r);
  }
 ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('in destroy' + this.r);
    if (this.r === false) {
this.router.navigate(['user-details']);
  window.history.pushState({}, "user-details", "/user-details");
  this.router.navigate(["user-details"]);
  window.location.reload();
    }
    // this.location.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you accessing `window.history` on your own? That's what the router is for.

Comment: I tried it as an alternative because this.router.navigate() was not working as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: `window.history` is just changing the URL because that's exactly what the function you're calling is supposed to do. You're approaching the problem from the wrong perspective. Instead of trying to fix it with the history API, figure out why was router not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why `this.router.navigate(['url'])` is not working. So I changed it to `this.router.navigateByUrl('/url')` method. Also,boolean value will be `undefined` at the starting time so need to check for that also.
both of these changes inside  `ngOnDestroy()` worked for me.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('in destroy' + this.r);
    if (this.r === false) {
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/user-details');

    } else if ( !this.r )  {
           this.router.navigateByUrl("/user-details");
    }
    // this.location.unsubscribe();
  }
```